# What is the proper name for this type-trait-like struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have the following struct which can be specialized to provide customized methods for construction of an object.

```
// Default implementation for types that accept a ParameterInfo reference.
template <typename T>
struct Loader::Construct {
    static Loader::ParameterInfo &construct(Loader::ParameterInfo &info);
};

// Specializations for common types.
template <>
struct Loader::Construct<int> {
    static int construct(Loader::ParameterInfo &info);
};
template <>
struct Loader::Construct<unsigned int> {
    static unsigned int construct(Loader::ParameterInfo &info);
};
template <>
struct Loader::Construct<std::string> {
    static std::string construct(Loader::ParameterInfo &info);
};
```

Is this a type trait, despite simply providing a specializable function implementation? Is there some other common name for such a construct?

Comment: Don't think I would call that a type trait. Traits usually tell you something about the type rather than providing functionality based on it.

Comment: For me, it's an implementation of builder design pattern or something like that

Comment: http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html is interesting. My first thought that led me to this page is a *policy*, but feels more like an *object generator*.